# How to Maintain SVG Styles (colors) When Morphing Between Paths with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg, gsap, svg-animate

I have an and animated map I am working on: https://codepen.io/robertsaget/pen/WNaJWmM

I am have 23 icons that morph from alert signals (red and white) to a speech bubbles (various colors) as the user scrolls. The animation is working correctly, but I cannot get the colors designated in the SVG to be respected during the animation.

For instance, I want the red alert icon to change to orange or blue (whichever is designated by the associated speech bubble path) when the user scrolls, and I want it to happen at the same speed as the morph animation, so that the color changes gradually and stops when the morph is complete.

**Here are my styles**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFCA19;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st2{fill:#279CD7;}
    .st3{fill:#E44D25;}
    .st4{fill:#E1A6CA;}
    .st5{fill:#F68C22;}
    .st6{fill:#3B2F8F;}
    .st7{fill:#70BE54;}
</style>
```

**Here is an example of one of the 23 iconsets:**

```
<g id="iconset1">
    <path id="bub1" d="M83.5 110.2c0-7.6-6.1-13.7-13.7-13.7s-13.7 6.1-13.7 13.7 6.1 13.7 13.7 13.7h.8l-1.5 3.7 9-6.4c3.3-2.5 5.4-6.5 5.4-11z" class="st2"/>
    <path id="altbg1" d="M76.7 118.1H62.9c-1.1 0-2-.6-2.6-1.5-.5-.9-.5-2 0-3l6.9-11.9c.5-.9 1.5-1.5 2.6-1.5s2 .6 2.6 1.5l6.9 11.9c.5.9.5 2 0 3-.6 1-1.6 1.5-2.6 1.5z" class="st1"/>
    <path id="alt1" d="m79.3 113.5-6.9-11.9c-.6-.9-1.5-1.5-2.6-1.5s-2.1.6-2.6 1.5l-6.9 11.9c-.5 1-.5 2.1 0 3 .6.9 1.5 1.5 2.6 1.5h13.8c1 0 2-.5 2.6-1.5.5-1 .5-2 0-3zm-7.9 1.8h-3.2v-2.9h3.2v2.9zm.1-9.4c0 1.4-.7 5.1-.7 5.5h-2c0-.3-.7-4.1-.7-5.4v-1.8h3.4v1.7z" class="st3"/>
  </g>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  div-align: center;
  height: 80%;
}

[id^="bub"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}


body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

**Here is my JS:**

```
let main_tl = []; 
let iconmorphComplete = []; 
let animationStarted = false;

function iconmorph(altSelector, bubSelector) {
  let tl = new TimelineMax();
  let s_tl = new TimelineMax();
  tl.to(altSelector, 3, {morphSVG: bubSelector}, "start");
  tl.eventCallback("onComplete", function() {
    iconmorphComplete[altSelector] = true;
  });
  return tl;
}

function handleScroll() {
  const scrollPercentage = (window.scrollY / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight)) * 100;

  if (scrollPercentage >= 0 && !animationStarted) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
      const altSelector = "#alt" + i;
      const bubSelector = "#bub" + i;
      main_tl[altSelector] = iconmorph(altSelector, bubSelector);
      animationStarted = true;
    }
  }

  if (animationStarted) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
      const altSelector = "#alt" + i;
      const progress = (scrollPercentage - 0) / (120 - 0); 
      if (!iconmorphComplete[altSelector]) {
        main_tl[altSelector].progress(progress).pause();
      }
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

I tried modifying my code with each of the following, but neither worked:

```
function iconmorph(altSelector, bubSelector) {
  let tl = new TimelineMax();
  let s_tl = new TimelineMax();
  
  // Set initial styles for altSelector and bubSelector
  tl.set(altSelector, { fill: 'currentColor' }); // Use currentColor to inherit color from the SVG
  tl.set(bubSelector, { fill: 'currentColor' });

  tl.to(altSelector, 3, { morphSVG: bubSelector }, "start");
  tl.eventCallback("onComplete", function() {
    iconmorphComplete[altSelector] = true;
  });
  
  return tl;
}
```

and

```
function iconmorph(altSelector, bubSelector) {
  let tl = new TimelineMax();
  let s_tl = new TimelineMax();

  // Get the initial color of altSelector
  const altColor = $(altSelector).attr('fill');

  // Set initial styles for altSelector and bubSelector
  tl.set(altSelector, { fill: altColor });
  tl.set(bubSelector, { fill: 'currentColor' });

  tl.to(altSelector, 3, { morphSVG: bubSelector }, "start");
  tl.to(altSelector, 3, { fill: 'currentColor' }, "start"); // Transition color to currentColor
  tl.to(bubSelector, 3, { fill: altColor }, "start"); // Transition color to altColor

  tl.eventCallback("onComplete", function() {
    iconmorphComplete[altSelector] = true;
  });

  return tl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function iconmorph(altSelector, bubSelector) {
  let tl = new TimelineMax();
  let s_tl = new TimelineMax();  
  const altColor = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(bubSelector)).getPropertyValue("fill");
tl.to(altSelector, 3, { fill: altColor }, "start");
  tl.to(altSelector, 3, {morphSVG: bubSelector}, "start");
  tl.eventCallback("onComplete", function() {
    iconmorphComplete[altSelector] = true;
  });
  return tl;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).